# Import multi file dat in vba array

Tags: arrays, vba, arraylist

I want to import multiple dat files into one with sheet with sheet name "selectfile" and into table with name "TableDat".
The actual record is 100000. I tried the code below for fast but I haven't been able to get all the data files into one sheet as I want the output to look like in the excel screenshot below. If there are other recommendations that are very fast then I accept. I attached a screenshot of the dat file as well.

thanks
roy

```
Sub importmultidat()

Dim myFileNames As Variant
Dim iCtr As Long
myFileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(filefilter:="DAT Files, *.DAT", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(myFileNames) Then
For iCtr = LBound(myFileNames) To UBound(myFileNames)
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myFileNames(iCtr), _
Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, _
Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)
Next iCtr
End If

End Sub
```

[image: datfile]
[image: result excel.]

Comment: @FaneDuru , 
maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub importmultidat()
    Dim V, W, F%, R&, X, S, L&, Y
        V = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test dat file update\":  If Dir(V & "*.dat") > "" Then ChDrive V: ChDir V
        W = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text files,*.dat", , "Select files(s)", , True):  If Not IsArray(W) Then Exit Sub
        F = FreeFile
        R = 2
    With Sheets("selectfile")
       .UsedRange.Clear
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ReDim V(.Rows.Count - 2, 1 To 4)
    For Each X In W
        Open X For Input As #F
        S = Split(Input(LOF(F), #F), vbCrLf)
        Close #F
    For L = 0 To UBound(S) + (S(UBound(S)) = "")
        Y = Split(S(L), vbTab)
    If IsDate(Y(1)) Then
        V(L, 4) = Split(Y(1), "-", 2)(0)
    Else
        Y(1) = Replace(Replace(Y(1), "--", "/"), "-", "")
        V(L, 4) = Split(Y(1), "/", 2)(0)
    End If
        V(L, 1) = Y(0)
        V(L, 2) = Y(1)
        V(L, 3) = Split(Y(1))(0)
    Next
       .Cells(R, 1).Resize(L, UBound(V, 2)).Value = V
        R = R + L
    Next
       .[A1:G1] = [{"ID","DATE & TIME","DATE","YEAR","PERIOD","CATEGORY","NAME"}]
       .ListObjects.Add 1, .[A1].CurrentRegion, , 1
    End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```